# How to Refresh the token that i got from google oauth 2.0 in iOS

Tags: ios, post, youtube-api, oauth-2.0

I am making an iOS application that uses the user's google account to get data from his youtube account and show them ....
first step is done using the gtm2 to authenticate the user and get an acces-token and a refresh-token 
the problem is that the access-token expires after 60 minutes and i have to login and allow the application again... 
i have found that you can use the refresh-token to get a new access-token
using this from the documetation :
--> my question is how to make a POST request to get the access token in objective-c
this is the data i need to use:

```
POST /o/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1

Host: accounts.google.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=21302922996.apps.googleusercontent.com&
client_secret=XTHhXh1SlUNgvyWGwDk1EjXB&
refresh_token=1/6BMfW9j53gdGImsixUH6kU5RsR4zwI9lUVX-tqf8JXQ&
grant_type=refresh_token
```

this is the code i am using :

```
NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"client_secret=%@&grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=%@&client_id%@",kGoogleClientSecretKey,kRefreshToken,kGoogleClientIDKey];
    NSLog(@"%@",post);
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"];

    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] ;
    [request setURL:url];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];


    NSError *error;
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    NSString *data=[[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@",data);
```

the error i get is :
{
  "error" : "invalid_request"
}

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Objective-C client library, but most of the other languages' client libraries have support for automatically refreshing the OAuth 2 token for you when you make a request using an expired access token. Are you sure that you need to manually refresh? If so, the best place to ask is probably https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/gdata-objectivec-client

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a `=` in your format string.

Change

```
NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"client_secret=%@&grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=%@&client_id%@",kGoogleClientSecretKey,kRefreshToken,kGoogleClientIDKey];
```

to

```
NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"client_secret=%@&grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=%@&client_id=%@",kGoogleClientSecretKey,kRefreshToken,kGoogleClientIDKey];
```