# How to get a new access token after expiration using OAuth 2.0 along with Youtube API in iOS application

Tags: objective-c, youtube-api, oauth-2.0, xcode4.5, access-token

I am using the Youtube Api in my iPad application. i managed to get authenticated and get the access token using the OAuth 2.0.
my problem is that the token expires after one hour and i don't know how to get a new one using the refresh-token without going through the authentication process again.
i am using XCode 4.5 and iOS 5.1 & 6

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Refresh the token that i got from google oauth 2.0 in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14014069/how-to-refresh-the-token-that-i-got-from-google-oauth-2-0-in-ios)

Comment: I am working on similar thing, I am not able to get access token using OAuth 2.0, can you please help me to get the access_token?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According do the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_oauth2#OAuth2_Refreshing_a_Token)

> If your application obtains a refresh token during the authorization process, then you will need to periodically use that token to obtain a new, valid access token. Server-side web applications, installed applications, and devices all obtain refresh tokens.

So if you already have your refresh token, you just need to perform a `POST` request configured as follows

```
POST /o/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: accounts.google.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=21302922996.apps.googleusercontent.com&
client_secret=<YOUR CLIENT SECRET>
refresh_token=<YOUR REFRESH TOKEN>
grant_type=refresh_token
```

and you'll get back a response like

```
{
  "access_token":<A NEW ACCESS TOKEN>,
  "expires_in":<AN EXPIRING TIME>,
  "token_type":"Bearer"
}
```

Comment: +Gabriele i tried that too : can you look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14014069/how-to-refresh-the-token-that-i-got-from-google-oauth-2-0-in-ios)

Comment: I'll take a look at that but duplicating your own question is not a good practice

Comment: it is not duplicated ! the first one was to know the proper way on how to refresh it using a POST Request.
and this one is about the whole approach .. so don't get confused !

Comment: it's surely more than related. Next time edit your original question.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the full code to refresh the accessToken using AFNetworking to make the request:

```
NSString *refreshToken = <YOUR_REFRESH_TOKEN>;

NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"client_secret=%@&grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=%@&client_id=%@",kYouTubeClientSecret,refreshToken,kYouTubeClientID];
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"];

AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

AFHTTPRequestOperation *httpRequest = [httpClient HTTPRequestOperationWithRequest:request
                                                                          success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                                                                              NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:kNilOptions error:nil];
                                                                              NSString *newAccessToken = json[@"access_token"];
                                                                              NSLog(@"received new accessToken = %@",newAccessToken);

                                                                              // store accessToken here

                                                                          } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                                                                              NSLog(@"error refreshing token: %@",[error localizedDescription]);

                                                                          }];
[httpClient enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:httpRequest];
```

Comment: thanks for this, resolved a 2 hour problem! 

I was initially using a dictionary to create the parameters and passing that as the body. But was giving me error that grant_type was no set. Your method of using the NSString with concatenated parameters is what resolved it.