# Authorization with gdata-objectivec-client

Tags: objective-c, youtube-api, gdata-objectivec-client

I am using gdata objectivec client to work with youtube v2.0. I don't want to ask user login many times. I want to login one time and get the accesstoken to use later. Please give me some sample codes to do this. Thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way is with the gtm-oauth2 library:

https://code.google.com/p/gtm-oauth2/

Here's a sample app that employs it:

https://github.com/stuffmc/YouTubeSample_iOS

Also reference this SO question:

[How to Refresh the token that i got from google oauth 2.0 in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14014069/how-to-refresh-the-token-that-i-got-from-google-oauth-2-0-in-ios)